# Morris chart with JSON data

Tags: php, json, morris.js

I have this code for outputting a db query (sql server) to a .json file on my local directory.

```
    $connectionInfo = array("");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn )
        {
      }else
        { echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }

   $sql="";
   $query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

    if( $query === false ) {
        echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $json = array();

    do {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $json[] = $row;
        }
    } while ( sqlsrv_next_result($query) );

        file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($json));
```

This part works fine and it's outputting json data in this format.

```
[{"month":1,"a":43,"b":10},{"month":2,"a":43,"b":87},{"month":3,"a":52,"b":11},{"month":4,"a":66,"b":25},{"month":5,"a":30,"b":11},{"month":6,"a":29,"b":10},{"month":7,"a":32,"b":41},{"month":8,"a":27,"b":36},{"month":9,"a":36,"b":32},{"month":10,"a":57,"b":57},{"month":11,"a":32,"b":20},{"month":12,"a":53,"b":65}]
```

On the other page i'm initializing this Morris-area-chart with the JSON data, like this:

**First i'm reading the JSON file and loop through the array.**

```
$final = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));
    $new_final = array();

    foreach($final as $value) {
        foreach($value as $sub_value) {
            $new_final[] = $sub_value;
        }
    }

        echo json_encode($new_final);
        exit;
    }
```

**Second im initializing the morris chart using Ajax on the same page using (document.url):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: document.URL,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_values: true},
        success: function(response) {

         Morris.Area({
                element: 'area-chart',
                data: response,
                xkey: 'month',
                ykeys: ['a','b'],
                labels: ['Month', 'Total']
            });
        }
    });

});
```

**It's not outputting the chart. I did found out that when you manipulate the .JSON file and add extra '[ ]', it is working correctly and outputting like expected, like this:**

```
[[{"month":1,"a":43,"b":10},{"month":2,"a":43,"b":87},{"month":3,"a":52,"b":11},{"month":4,"a":66,"b":25},{"month":5,"a":30,"b":11},{"month":6,"a":29,"b":10},{"month":7,"a":32,"b":41},{"month":8,"a":27,"b":36},{"month":9,"a":36,"b":32},{"month":10,"a":57,"b":57},{"month":11,"a":32,"b":20},{"month":12,"a":53,"b":65}]]
```

Could somebody tell me what i'm overseeing here? It looks like i need an second array but i'm not sure.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

```
$final = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));
    $new_final = array();

    foreach($final as $value) {
        foreach($value as $sub_value) {
            $new_final[] = $sub_value;
        }
    }

        echo json_encode($new_final);
        exit;
    }
```

Should be

```
$final = json_decode(file_get_contents('../php/data.json'));
    $new_final = array($final);

    foreach($final as $value) {

    }
        echo json_encode($final);
        exit;
    }
```